# Plotting two datasets

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to show two data sets: one with a lower opacity and the other with normal dots using D3.js. I tried this:

```
svg.selectAll("*").remove();

if (olddset!=dset) {
svg.selectAll("circle") .data(datasets[olddset]) .enter() .append("circle")
    .attr('cx',function(a){ return xscales[whichscale][xval](a[xval]); })
    .attr('cy',function(a){ return yscales[whichscale][yval](a[yval]); })
    .attr('r',1)
    .style("opacity", 0.2)
    ;
}

svg.selectAll("circle") .data(datasets[dset]) .enter() .append("circle")
    .attr('cx',function(a){ return xscales[whichscale][xval](a[xval]); })
    .attr('cy',function(a){ return yscales[whichscale][yval](a[yval]); })
    .attr('r',3)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    ;
```

However, that does not do what I was looking for. I wanted `olddset` to be small dots and the new dataset (`dset`) with `r=3` and `opacity=1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `svg.selectAll("circle2")` for the second dataset.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. And I learnt something new.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same selection for the first AND second dataset. Thus for the second dataset you are selecting `<circle>`s that already exist. Instead, use a different selection, for example:

```
svg.selectAll("circle2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with styles. Like:

```
svg.selectAll("circle.oldset").data(datasets[olddset]).enter().append("circle")
    .attr('cx',function(a){ return xscales[whichscale][xval](a[xval]); })
    .attr('cy',function(a){ return yscales[whichscale][yval](a[yval]); })
    .attr('r',1)
    .classed("oldset", true); // where the oldset class in yr styles has the opacity defined

svg.selectAll("circle.dset") .data(datasets[dset]) .enter() .append("circle")
    .attr('cx',function(a){ return xscales[whichscale][xval](a[xval]); })
    .attr('cy',function(a){ return yscales[whichscale][yval](a[yval]); })
    .attr('r',3)
    .classed("dset", true);
```

You will run into trouble with the "circle2" trick if you try to update because it will never select anything.